# Highlight regions of the US map

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for a tool to Highlight regions of the US map.
Cities, states or metropolitan areas. If it is an online tool much better.

Edit:

Found it:

https://drive.google.com/templates?type=drawings&sort=user&view=public&ddrp=1#